# Compilation error "Could not load type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo>'" in web deploy project. Asp.net mvc rc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment

i'm getting the below error, When compiling the Asp.Net web deploy project

Could not load type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo>'.    /Shared/Error.aspx

But when I compile the web project, It is not showing any error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that there is appropriate dll files in your bin folder on deployment server.

System.Web.Abstractions.dll

System.Web.Mvc.dll

System.Web.Routing.dll

Also, make sure that web.config contains proper configuration for those dlls in compilation/assemblies section:

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

Here is example for 1.0 version of MVC, you should insert yours (for RC2)