# asp.net mvc 3 Parser Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, parse-error

I create new asp.net mvc 3 project.
Copy there all controllers, classes and views from my asp.net mvc 2 project.
Include all references

And now have error

**Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage'.**

Source Error:

```
Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Abbono.Models.LogOnModel>" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert your application from mvc 2 to mvc 3 follow instruction from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/01/13/mvc-3-project-upgrade-tool.aspx) or you may get help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566297/compilation-error-could-not-load-type-system-web-mvc-viewpagesystem-web-mvc-ha)

Answer (score 0):

@mola, message "Could not load type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage'" says that your project doesn't see "System.Web.Mvc.dll" library.

Check in root web.config file next section:

```
<configuration>

  <system.web>

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Also verify that you have installed MVC 3 dll.
You can check existance of file "System.Web.Mvc.dll" in directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\"